# Как найти изображение в другом изображении при помощи JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли на сегодня готовые решения в виде библиотеки\скрипта на JavaScript для поиска изображения в другом изображении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Предложу несколько вариантов, по возрастанию сложности...

- **fast-average-color**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрите [этот файл](https://github.com/fast-average-color/fast-average-color/blob/master/src/algorithm/simple.js) исходного кода модуля. Можно не сравнивать картинки попиксельно, а вынести вердикт исходя из люфта красного, зеленого и синего цвета у двух изображений.

https://github.com/fast-average-color/fast-average-color

- **node-sift-distance**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вас интересует не именно эта библиотека, а [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform): это единственный алгоритм сравнения изображений, доступный людям без математической подготовки и не требующий обучения нейросети (две картинки на вход, множество общих точек на выходе)

https://github.com/jhermsmeier/node-sift-distance

- **tfjs-yolo**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разпознавание изображений на основе нейросети [Yolo](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/). Если тренированные заранее модели не устроят, придется делать свои, что потребует много сил и системный блок с видеокартой Nvidia и поддержкой CUDA. Благо, у библиотеки есть [онлайн демо](https://shaqian.github.io/tfjs-yolo-demo/), позволяющее убедиться в ее работоспособности.

https://github.com/shaqian/tfjs-yolo